# Servlet with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, httpresponse

In my servlet I have this code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Utils.CheckSession(request,response);

    String op = request.getParameter("op");
    int DaysToAdd = request.getParameter("daysToAdd") != null ? Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("daysToAdd")) :  0;

    ArrayList<Giorno> giorni = new ArrayList<Giorno>();

    /*HERE I FILL ArrayList giorni and calculate other variables*/


    if ("cal".equals(op))
    {
        request.setAttribute("giorni", giorni);
        request.setAttribute("daysToAdd", DaysToAdd);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("GestioneCalendario.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    else if("utente".equals(op))
    {
        // ricavare abbonamento dell'utente
        String idu = (String) request.getAttribute("idu");
        Abbonamento a = null;
        int iDa = Utils.getIdAbbonamentoAttivoUtente(idu);
        a = Utils.getAbbonamentoFromId(iDa);
        request.setAttribute("abbonamento", a);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Lezioni.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    else
    {
        request.setAttribute("giorni", giorni);
        request.setAttribute("daysToAdd", DaysToAdd);       
        request.getRequestDispatcher("GestioneLezioniNuovoLayout.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Maybe the problem is in the method CheckSession??

```
public static void CheckSession(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
     String logged = null;
     if (session!=null)
          logged = (String) session.getAttribute("logined");
     if(logged == null)
     {
         request.setAttribute("errore", "Devi loggarti!");
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin.jsp")
            .forward(request, response);
            return;
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

but it gives me this exception:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TakeDates] in context with path [/Spinning] threw     exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at servlet.TakeDates.doGet(TakeDates.java:368)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

the servlet is called with this url

```
http://localhost:8080/Spinning/TakeDates?op=cal
```

Anyone can help me? thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire method. Can you please provide.

Comment: @robbmj: the methos is really really long :|

Comment: Fair enough, just look for a line where you have written to the response writer before forwarding the request. If you find one then that is the problem

Comment: @robbmj I edited the question with my code, maybe the problem is in the CheckSession Method that I call initially in my servlet?

Comment: @robbmj I'm quite sure that the problem is with CheckSession. If the user is not logged, the code after istruction Utils.CheckSession() is executed.

Comment: Okay I see your problem in the `CheckSession` method. See answers for details

Comment: @MartinaF what line of code you have at `TakeDates.doGet(TakeDates.java:368)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have committed some response to the response object.

You have to dispatch to your `jsp` page before you commit any output to the `response object`.

From the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

> forward should be called before the response has been committed to the
>   client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response
>   already has been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. Uncommitted output in the response buffer is
>   automatically cleared before the forward.

The problem is that you are forwarding to the admin.jsp page when you should be redirecting in the `Utils.CheckSession` method

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**Should be**

```
response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp");
return false;

// in the doGet method
if (!Utils.CheckSession(request,response)) {
    return;
}
```

Redirects do not happen immediately, the `servlet` will continue execution and when it hits the next `RequestDispatcher.forward` call the `exception` is raised.

The server needs to send the http: redirect status code in the http response, the browser then receives the response and requests resource specified by the redirect url.

Comment: but I have to pass the error string...

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp?errore=Dave+loggarti!");`

Comment: You're right. But I tried and didn't works. Also with return; :(

Comment: what exactly did not work?

Comment: If CheckSession is ok it Works fine.
If CheckSession is ko, istructions after CheckSession(request, response) are in every case executed. And the error is the same of the question.

Comment: If the CheckSession does response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp?errore=Dave+loggarti!"); I have not to Execute istructions of the servlet.

Comment: You have to structure your code that execution does not happen when the Session is invalid and only the redirect occurs.

Comment: thank you, so I have to change my metod checkSession to Boolean. sigh.
Thank you very much for your help and your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Include a foward slash ie '/' on your urls. I had the same problem and a simple foward slash came to my rescue.