# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

In a JSF webapplication that is developed by using primefaces and omnifaces, the following error occurs in RESTORE_VIEW phase when session is timed out.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host]. (ajp-executor-threads - 1694) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/pages/standardErrorPage.xhtml' will be shown.: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/pages/myPage.jsf - View /pages/myPage.jsf could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.1.23-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.23-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.23-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.23-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.execute(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:95) [myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-impl-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.23.Final.jar:2.1.23.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.5.7.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:56) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:148) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:180) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:847)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host]] (ajp-executor-threads - 1694) JBWEB000313: Exception processing error page /pages/standardErrorPage.xhtml: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000029: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:682) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:702) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:515) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:370) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:847)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

From my analysis on Omnifaces documentations, I guess that, the exception is due to an attribute called `ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_EXCEPTION` in HttpServletRequest object. But it should have been removed as I am using the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler#handle()` from omnifaces.

```
Events.addCallbackAfterPhaseListener(PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE, new Callback.Void() {
    @Override
    public void invoke() {
        request.removeAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_EXCEPTION);
    }
});
```

The above piece of code didn't removed that attribute.

Can I remove that attribute to get rid of that error?
What is the main purpose of that attribute? and 
How to overcome the java.lang.IllegalStateException: in this scenario?

Comment: Looks like you're using an older OmniFaces version. Any chance to try the latest? Regardless, the full stack trace is always helpful.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have updated the full stacktrace. I am using omnifaces version 1.5. It would be great, if i can resolve this in the same version.

Comment: Any idea on this guys...??

Comment: Try OmniFaces 1.11 to exclude an already fixed bug from being the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You committed response before forwarding.
for more details see these questions :

[Servlet with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743803/servlet-with-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has)

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot (forward | sendRedirect | create session) after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-sendredirect-create-session)